# Retrieve all values that partly contains values from a list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table in my database called `Citites`. I want to retrieve all cities whose name contain any of the values from the `strings` list.

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>(new string[] {"burg", "wood", "town"} );
```

I tried this but it will only match the exact value from the strings list. I need to find values that contain e.g `town`, like `cape town` and `townsend`

```
List<City> cities = db.Cities.Where(c => strings.Contains(c.name));
```

**EDIT**
I'm using `LINQ to SQL` and `Any()` doesn't seem to be supported here:

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query
>   operators except the Contains operator.

Comment: with questions like this it is very important to note what kind of LINQ provider you are using - is it Linq-to-sql, Entity Framework (then which version) etc. This is because each provider supports a different set of expressions.

Comment: @Knaģis - Good point, it's updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention that your LINQ provider does not support .Any() in this context, here is a much more complicated code that builds the query expression dynamically.

```
var strings = new [] { "burg", "wood", "town" };
// just some sample data
var cities = new[] { new City("Capetown"), new City("Hamburg"), new City("New York"), new City("Farwood") };

var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(City));
var cityName = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Name"); // change the property name
Expression condition = Expression.Constant(false);
foreach (var s in strings)
{
    var expr = Expression.Call(cityName, "Contains", Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Constant(s));
    condition = Expression.OrElse(condition, expr);
}

// you can apply the .Where call to any query. In the debugger view you can see that
// the actual expression applied is just a bunch of OR statements.
var query = cities.AsQueryable().Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<City, bool>>(condition, param));
var results = query.ToList();

// the class used in the test
private class City
{
    public City(string name) { this.Name = name; }
    public string Name;
}
```

But note that since you mentioned in other comments that the `strings` collection is rather large, you should really look into building a stored procedure and pass the values as XML parameter to that procedure (then load the XML as table and join it in the query) because this approach of building the query will probably soon run into some sort of "query has too many operands" exception.

Comment: This is the solution I went with. I don't know if it's the quickest but it solves my problem.

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you need, assuming your LINQ provider supports it - since you did not mention what are you using, we can't test it.

```
List<City> cities = db.Cities.Where(c => strings.Any(s => c.name.Contains(s)));
```

---

In detail: for a single value (like `Capetown`) you would write

```
strings.Any(s => "Capetown".Contains(s))
```

Then you just apply this expression inside your current `Where` condition as shown in the initial code example.

Comment: `c` is a city which has a property name, so `c.Contains` doesn't work.

Comment: I don't have support for `Any()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is supported by your LINQ-provider, but at least in LINQ-To-Objects this works:

```
List<City> cities = db.Cities.Where(c => strings.Any(s=> c.Name.Contains(s)));
```

Comment: I'm running LINQ-to-SQL and it doesn't seem to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the City name contains any of the string in the list, not the other way around:

```
protected bool ContainsSubstring(string cityName, List<string> strings)
{
 foreach(string subString in strings)
 {
  if (cityName.Contains(subString)) return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

...

```
List<City> cities = db.Cities.Where(c => this.ContainsSubstring(c.name, strings));
```

Comment: If you don't have support for Any(), this should work.

Comment: That's a lot of calls if I have 200 values in my `strings` list. Is this really the only way to solve it?

Comment: In order not to make so many db calls, you can define your own predicate, to check through all substrings at once, I will edit my post.

Comment: Now it should work, with fewer calls to the db. Just need to add the ContainsSubstring method in the same class for that particular call to work. Or you can change the call, perhaps make the method static.

Answer (score 0):

If you find it with a lot of loops, try using FUNC<> which will be better (in performance). I have a sample for that :

```
            List<string> _lookup = new List<string>() { "dE", "SE","yu" };
            IEnumerable<string> _src = new List<string> { "DER","SER","YUR" };

            Func<string, List<string>, bool> test = (i,lookup) =>
            {
                bool ispassed = false;

                foreach (string lkstring in lookup)
                {
                    ispassed = i.Contains(lkstring, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

                    if (ispassed) break;
                }

                return ispassed;

            };


            var passedCities = _src.Where(i => test(i, _lookup));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cities = from c in db.Cities.AsEnumerable()
             from s in strings
             where c.name.ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower())
             select c.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ability to call a stored proc or sql? - you could use SQL fulltextsearch, especially if you're searching multiple terms. It'd probably be a lot quicker than doing string comparisons in SQL.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx

You could create your search terms by doing `string.Join(" ", strings)`